# Connecting to remote device via hostname that gets its IP from DHCP

Tags: ip, dhcp, dns

I currently manage ~600 devices in remote sites. We use a proprietary software to monitor these devices, and currently configure static IPs for every device.

This requires us to have knowledge of what switch it will be plugged into, which is often hard because we aren't on site during installs. also, devices can be moved without our knowledge, and the only way to bring it back online is to have them reconnected to the original switch.

Would there be an issue with allowing the device to get an IP from DHCP and connecting to it via hostname? If this were to work, we wouldn't need knowledge of which switch is closest to the rack we are installing it in, and would prevent us from losing connection if a device is moved.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why moving a device to a different switch is a problem unless you have multiple subnets on switches.  In addition to DHCP, you will need  DDNS.

Answer (score 3):

If your DHCP and DNS servers both implement DDNS (that's Dynamic [updates] to DNS, I know ISC's Open Source servers do this, and I'm sure there are several others), you can have the DHCP server update the DNS each time it gives out a lease.  If you do that right, the name each system wants will be registered in the DNS.  Notice that there are some complications if more than one device wants the same name.  They are usually first come first serve, unless overridden in the server config.

Answer (score -2):

SNMP server settings are configured on the client(s).  So, if you are using SNMP your server gets messages that way.  If you are not using SNMP, you might try pushing out DHCP option with manager ip address.  Client would need to be configured somehow to get this value though.

Comment: I'm not sure where SNMP came from, it doesn't seem to have been in the original question.

Comment: I understood the question to be about managing networking devices - hundreds of them.  I believe the OP was asking how to communicate with managed devices when you don't know their IP address beforehand.  SNMP is a widely used network management protocol where the remote devices are given the management server(s) address thus mitigating the OP's issue.